# How to embed youtube videos in mdx files using Next.js with Nextra library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, mdxjs

I am using this [Portfolio Starter Kit](https://github.com/kristjanr/what-does-this-button-do#readme) for my travel blog. The only feature I am missing there is a way to embed youtube videos into the blog post, so that they would play on-the-spot, without opening the video on youtube.com on a new page.

I used ChatGPT-s help, but since I am new to Next.js and Nextra I am unable to spot ChatGPT-s mistakes and debug them. This was it's recommendation:

1. Install the react-youtube package in your project:

   ```
   yarn add react-youtube
   ```
2. Create a custom MDX component to render YouTube videos:
   Create a new file in your project directory called YouTube.js. In this file, define a new component that uses the YouTube component from the react-youtube library to render YouTube videos. Here is an example of what this file could look like:

   ````
   import YouTube from 'react-youtube';

   const YouTubeComponent = ({ videoId }) => {
     const opts = {
       height: '360',
       width: '640',
       playerVars: {
         // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
         autoplay: 0,
       },
     };

     return <YouTube videoId={videoId} opts={opts} />;
   };

   export default YouTubeComponent;```
   ````
3. Register the custom MDX component in your Next.js configuration:
   In your Next.js configuration file (usually [next.config.js](https://github.com/kristjanr/what-does-this-button-do/blob/main/next.config.js)), you can register the YouTubeComponent as a custom MDX component by adding the following code:

   ```
   const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
     extension: /\.mdx?$/,
     options: {
       remarkPlugins: [],
       rehypePlugins: [],
       // Register custom components here
       // Here, we're registering a component called 'youtube' that uses our custom YouTubeComponent
       components: {
         youtube: './components/YouTube',
       },
     },
   });

   module.exports = withMDX();
   ```
4. Use the custom component in your Markdown content:
   In your Markdown content, you can now use the 'youtube' tag to embed YouTube videos. Here is an example of what this could look like:

   ```
   Here is a YouTube video:

   <youtube videoId="dQw4w9WgXcQ" />
   ```

After adding all this and runnin `yarn run build` I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./pages/ajaveeb/2023-02-18-youtube-embedding.mdx
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)
    at Object.relative (node:path:1191:5)
    at loader (file:///Users/kristjan.roosild/repos/what-does-this-button-do/node_modules/nextra/dist/loader.mjs:85:42)
```

Here is the PR of the changes https://github.com/kristjanr/what-does-this-button-do/pull/1/files

Answer (score 0):

for typescript use this
import YouTube, { YouTubeProps } from 'react-youtube';

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate - where should I add this line? Will it fix the issue I have? Have you tested it out with my code?

Comment: in your component file

Comment: This answer is not worthy of the bounty. It did not help me solve my problem. I'll consider dropping the usage of nextra and use next-mdx-remote instead.